# How to attach a file to an answer in this forum?

Tags: forum

I would like to add an Excel file to my posting/ answer in this forum, but can't find a way to to attach a file to to my posting/ answer.

Is that possible?

[Excelfile](https://filebin.net/ghuzex1tyvhr1l4u/Free_English_textbooks.xlsx?t=p86m9eqb)

Comment: you can share a link.

Comment: How can I share a link? Where has the file to be stored?

Comment: simply upload a file and post the link

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to be my day. I can't find a way to upload a file. How can I do this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related.